# Creating two versions of a slide deck

Tags: beamer, versions, includeonlylecture

I use beamer to prepare lecture slide decks for my classes. The solution, after the initial pain (far in excess of Keynote), works well, as it allows slide re-use in a fairly straightforward manner. I make minor improvements in each run of the course, and the slide deck has gotten incrementally quite good.

I use '''\lecture{}{}''' and '''\appendix''' in conjunction with '''\includeonlylecture''' to separate out individual lectures in a course (call it course A) over a semester.

Now, I am supposed to teach a different course (call it course B) next term, and this course has a nearly 65% overlap with the one I have a slide deck for. Normally, I would simply start a new slide deck for that class, and treat it as a separate course deserving of a separate set of slides.

I do not want to do that. Reason: I am going to be teaching courses A and B repeatedly over the next few years. The two courses logically address the same material, but each has a different emphasis, requiring different examples, and slightly different math in the common portion. It is quite possible that the two courses will be merged into a common first course, followed by two separate courses as follow-on courses, in a few years. So, given the synergy, I need a different way of doing things.

My vision of this was - I could define a course code-driven "mode" (not presentation vs handout as is inbuilt in beamer, but rather presentation A vs presentation B) that will be defined as a global mode in the common slide deck, but merely selecting one or the other (using a fictitious '''\selectcourse{X}''' directive for instance), allow me to teach both courses from a single slide deck. Please note - it is not just the slides that are different, even parts of the same slide may be slightly different between courses A and B. I want a switchable newenvironment that can perhaps defined as \if{A}\then{1}\elseif{B}{2} etc.

I could define a new environment and go that way on my own. What I am asking is if beamer has an inbuilt set of primitives that will allow me to do this rightaway instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: in CTAN you will find several packages for [`conditional compilation`](https://www.ctan.org/topic/cond-comp). `Beamer` provides a `beamerarticle` option to share a complete article with a presentation into the same tex file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `beameraudience` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[
audience=coursea
%audience=courseb
]{beameraudience}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    frame for both
  
  \showcontentfor{coursea}{only for a}
  
  \showcontentfor{courseb}{only for b}
\end{frame} 

\justfor{coursea}{  
\begin{frame}
    only for a
\end{frame} 
}

\justfor{courseb}{  
\begin{frame}
    only for b
\end{frame} 
}
    
\end{document}
```